# Enable/Disable Rotation, Pan, Zoom in Camera COntrols

Tags: animation, three.js, react-three-fiber, orbitcontrols

Is there any way to disable/enable only the rotation, pan, zoom options in [Camera Controls](https://github.com/yomotsu/camera-controls).

In that, the `enabled` option sets enabled or disables all controls. But I need to specify the options like zoom, pan or rotation.

Answer (score 0):

I was about to post the same problem. Turns out that I found a workaround. You can try disabling the camera controls and temporarily instantiate an orbit control.

```
    const orbitControls = new OrbitControls(
      viewer.camera.get(),
      viewer.ui.viewerContainer
    );

///setting same mouse button configurations
    orbitControls.mouseButtons = {
      LEFT: THREE.MOUSE.ROTATE,
    };
```

also don't forget to capture the animation frame id so you can get rip of it later on

```
let animationLoopId;
function animate() {
  animationLoopId =
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  orbitControls.update();
  viewer.renderer
    .get()
    .render(scene, viewer.camera.get());
}
animate();
```

later on, you can dispose it and get back to work with camera controls:
...

```
cancelAnimationFrame(animationLoopId!);
orbitControls.dispose();
controls.enabled = true;
```

Hope this helps!